# Is there a way to do a high voltage insulation check on a wire without grounding it?

Tags: high-voltage, insulation, insulation-voltage

So far we are using a common HV tester to check the insulation (green) of a wire:

[image]

It has coal brushes (thin blue) at 1000 V, the wire core (orange) is PE. Short-circuit or leakage create a fault current. Easy-peasy.

Now we are looking for a solution without grounding the wire core.

The first things that came to our mind were eddy current and running the wire through a solenoid.

Do you have ideas how this could be implemented?

Comment: You don’t have to _ground_ it, just create a potential difference. Do you have access to the conductor?

Comment: Usually HiPot testers test for *leakage*.  Meaning they don't need to short, just have some small current flow.  Think of  a crack in the insulation that the coal brush doesn't reach into, you still want to know about that.

Comment: It is grounded, so far the conductor is fixed to the housing of one of the production machines. But in the future we won't have access to the conductor anymore.

Comment: So you want to test a wire's insulation that you don't have physical access to?

Comment: We measure leakage and also actual holes in the insulation where it shorts.

Comment: We have full access to the wire, we just can't attach anything to the conductor. We can build anything near or around the wire.

Comment: We also thought about keeping the solution with the brushes and creating a potential difference in the conductor by induction as replacement for the grounding.

Comment: I assume the wire is guided through some wheel groups on its way through the machine. In my experience these wheels introduce large static charges up to some kV in the wire core if not grounded. The reason is bending and tumble forces on the insulator. On stranded wire this effect is less critical. So in a first attempt, I recommend to measure the core voltage relative to GND while the wire is moving without any HV tester voltage applied. Wire cutting blades can be eroded by high discharge currents of the wire core.

Comment: Jens, thanks for the helpful comment. Yes, the wire is running through a straightener and we will try to measure the effect you mentioned.